# AsyncTaskLoader not changing value

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

Hi i am trying to load some data from msql db using asynctaskloader .

```
int customerid=0;
public void loaddata(int custId) {
    customerid = custid;
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}


@Override public Loader<List<AppEntry>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created.  This
    // sample only has one Loader with no arguments, so it is simple.
    return new AppListLoader(getActivity(),customerid);
}

@Override public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<AppEntry>> loader, List<AppEntry> data) {
    // Set the new data in the adapter.
    log.d("price of item",""+data);
}

@Override public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<AppEntry>> loader) {
    // Clear the data in the adapter.
}
```

i am calling the loaddata() method from an activity and passing different customer id each time ,but it only gives me old result what i passed first time. 
It is there something call notify adapter change as we have in other adapters.

Comment: please fix your formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initLoader` only starts the loader once and calls to it again do nothing per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#initLoader%28int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks%3CD%3E%29):

> If the loader doesn't already exist, one is created and (if the activity/fragment is currently started) starts the loader. Otherwise the last created loader is re-used.

You want to use [restartLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#restartLoader%28int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks%3CD%3E%29) in its place if you want to call it multiple times.

Comment: Thanks , i think it will work let me try and is bundle is used to pass value here ,to the asyncloader class or i need to create a new constructor to pass the value ?

Comment: Yes ,it workd . Thank you so much . One question ,can i use as many loader in once class . Does using so many loader will make any problem

Comment: @SureshBora - yes, you can use multiple loaders - just make sure to use a different loader id (the first parameter in your call to `initLoader`/`restartLoader`) for each one.

Comment: @Ianhanniballake-  ya thanks worked fine , is it possible to stop this loader forcefully .i want  a way so that i can  control the loading of data ,by my self. pressing button a load data pressing button b stops loadingdata and reset to default

Comment: @SureshBora - I assume you've already looked at [destroyLoader()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#destroyLoader(int)), which stops the loader and calls `onLoaderReset`?

Comment: @Ianhanniballake- yes Thanks , i saw now, Well one more thing, it is good idea to stop the loader once loading is finished as data in server is not changing . (Sorry for bad english)

Comment: @SureshBora - data will only reload when you call `restartLoader`, so there's no need to stop it if it already finished.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this but it will always resetart the loader on subsequent attempts:

```
 if(getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(Consts.LOADER_2)==null)
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(Consts.LOADER_2, null, this);
         else
             getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(Consts.LOADER_2, null, this);
```